# Campsites in Virginia which allow alcohol?

Tags: camping, alcohol

Shenandoah National Park allows alcohol, but it's a bit far from me for a one-night getaway with family.  Do you know of a list of camp sites in Northern VA which allow alcohol?

Comment: I see the votes to close, but I would like someone to explain them in the comments. I agree this is near the limits of our questions (not very GREAT outdoors if you can bring a case of beer) but I don't know a better SA site for this question and I could see it being useful. The Northern VA area has tons of great camping, some private and some public. I don't know which ones allow drinking but I would be interested in knowing. +1

Comment: Just don't make a lot of noise, and you'll be fine. Don't be loud and obnoxious, and clean up your mess, and no one will have a problem.

Comment: @JustinC I think this link to an answer about what is too localized for us might help. http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/22/527

Comment: I agree this isn't too localized at all! It's a question that could feasibly be useful to others, so is perfectly on topic as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I deem this too localized, and the fact that it doesn't have answers after 11 days all the more proves that. Perhaps try searching Google/Bing/Yahoo?

Comment: As someone who appreciates the outdoors for what they are, I'd rather you stay home and have your beer party your own back yard.  That said, as long as you don't act like a jerk and are discrete, nobody will notice and therefore care.  The problem is that most of the beer guzzling yahoos in the woods do act like jerks, so rules were made.